# Prove that $L=\{a^ib^jc^k\ |\ i\neq j,\ i\neq k,\ j\neq k\}$ satisfies the pumping lemma

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

I've faced this question while I was solving some past homework and I couldn't really figure out how I would solve it.

***Question:*** Prove that $L=\{a^ib^jc^k\ |\ i\neq j,\ i\neq k,\ j\neq k\}$ satisfies the pumping lemma even though it's ***not*** a CFL.

***Note:*** There's no need to prove that it's not a CFL.

The purpose of the question is to show that the pumping lemma is a necessary condition for a language being CFL but isn't enough to determine whether it's a CFL or not.

I have an idea to prove it but I couldn't write a formal and proper proof for it.

Comment: Oh, yea thanks it does.